# How to set different columns for rows in android gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to have a gridview similar to this

[image]

Every odd numbered row will have two images of big size and even numbered rows will have four smaller images.How can I achieve this?

Comment: [AsymetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView) might do what you want.

Comment: @mungaih pk  are you using `RecyclerView` with `GridView`?

Comment: @mungaih pk  have you tried my solution? tell me something, thanks!

Comment: @Xcihnegn am trying out your solution. I will get back to you. Thanks man.

Comment: Or, maybe you could use GridLayout with smallest image as one cell.. and  setting `RowSpan = 2` and `ColSpan = 2` for every image where `position%3 = 0`

Comment: recycleview is good one

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have something similar and i solved with the new RecyclerView.

I created a Fragment with an a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).
RecyclerView on xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/filter_subtypes" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

On your Fragment/Activity (OnViewCreated in my fragment case).
I find the RecyclerView and set an Adapter- a normal Adapter class inherit from ***RecyclerView.Adapter< YOUR VIEW HOLDER class >***-
And then i create a GridLayoutManager

```
final GridLayoutManager mng_layout = new GridLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), TOTAL_CELLS_PER_ROW/*In your case 4*/);
```

Then i override this method to set a dynamic numbers of columns (cells)

```
mng_layout.setSpanSizeLookup( new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch( adapterSubtype.getItemViewType(position) ) {
                    case FilterSubtypesAdapter.TYPE_LOW:
                        return TOTAL_CELLS_PER_ROW;
                    case FilterSubtypesAdapter.TYPE_HIGH:
                        return 2;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mng_layout);
```

With this you will get dynamic numbers of cell on your rows.

EXTRA:
Then if you are using the same view/type view on your adapter, you will get the same w & h view. You will need to create 2 xml views for TYPE_HIGH and other view for TYPE_LOW.

So, in your adapter, you need to have 2 kind of data (1 for high images and 1 for low images).
You must override this methods

```
@Override
public SubtypeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = null;
    if (viewType==TYPE_HIGH) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image_high, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image_low, parent, false);
    }
    return new SubtypeViewHolder(view, viewType);
}

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return (list.get(position).getType()==Subtype_type.HIGH) ? TYPE_HIGH : TYPE_LOW;
 }
```

I hope i was clear, any problem tell me.

Comment: I have been trying your example, but am encountering too many errors, could you please share you code for the adapter and the fragment. I will really appreciate.

Comment: Yeah no problem to show you my code, but it's long so if you tell me what kind of errors you get i can help you with that part

Comment: I don't know if pastebin it's a valid link on a stackoverflow post, so to help you i post here on the comment http://pastebin.com/Fy49p4sT, i rename my project packages with X, there are many dependencies and thing you don't need, i prefer if you tell me what the problem. but anyway there you have it, i hope it helps you :D

Comment: @Sulfkain.. This seems like reasonable solution but the URL you posted is no more accessible

Comment: @ArsalanShah sorry but i that was a temporally help, the solution it's on my answer, not in my code.

Comment: Working! Be aware that the int result of getSpanSize isn't the spanCount for this case, this int is the divider of your default spanCount. So, if you have in your manager spanCount = 4, to get a row of one item you have to return 4, to get a row of 2 items return 2, and to get a row of 4 items return 1.

Comment: @Pelanes You are the saint

Answer (score 24):

Instead of considering a single image views i am taking group of three images as a single grid item,

[image]

try this inside your grid adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
     />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/user"

            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/user"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and your grid view would be like

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    >

</GridView>
```

The only thing you have to take care of is, the sequence of your image. might be this will help you

Comment: The problem with that aproach it's with clickListeners, you don't know which image was clicked

Comment: I think you can access child image view with id in method public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)  with arg1.

Comment: What will be if one row with 3, and another row with 4?

Comment: This is not what i intend.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `RecyclerView` for `GridView`, then there is solution that should work for you:

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4);
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
         int mod = position % 6;    

         if(position == 0 || position == 1)
              return 2;
         else if(position < 6)
              return 1;
         else if(mod == 0 || mod == 1)
              return 2;
         else
              return 1;
    }
});

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: @Xchinegn, I am trying to implement your solution with max 3 and min 2 span. But not following. Can u guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way to do is using recycler view..
Also it is preferred over list/grid for performance

May be below links can help a lot - All are related to Two way View by Lucas

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

https://plus.google.com/+LucasRocha/posts/WBaryNqAHiy

http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/

Comment: this fork is more stable  =>  https://github.com/Superbalist/twoway-view

Comment: @javaacm how does it could be more stable if it is completely the same

Comment: `lucasr/twoway-view` is a stopped project for development (about 2 years is stopped) so some issues are important and if you see `Network` state at > https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/network and their commits detail `Superbalist`'s fork is more clean for working , anyway `lucasr` repo is Ok but if you dont want to have some features that reported in the issues section , in the `Superbalist`'s commit detail i see some important issues are fixed

Answer (score 1):

There is how does it work in my project I have different height of cells and also header

[image]

adapter:

```
public class AdapterRecViewMain
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList;
private final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
private final int FOOTER_VIEW = 1;

public AdapterRecViewMain() {
}

public void setData(List<BaseMarkerElement> mainCardList) {
    this.mainCardList = mainCardList;
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return HEADER_VIEW;
    }
    return FOOTER_VIEW;
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type) {
    if (type == FOOTER_VIEW) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new MainCardViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.header_view_main_activity, viewGroup, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int positionItem) {
    final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

    if (viewHolder instanceof HeaderViewHolder) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);

        BaseMarkerElement item = mainCardList.get(position);
        if (item instanceof HeaderView) {
            HeaderView header = (HeaderView) mainCardList.get(position);
            // need to add implementation
        }
    } else if (viewHolder instanceof MainCardViewHolder) {
        MainCardViewHolder currentView = (MainCardViewHolder) viewHolder;
        CardMainActivity currentCard = (CardMainActivity) mainCardList.get(position);

        currentView.ivMainCard.setImageResource(currentCard.getIvMainCard());
        currentView.tvBrandName.setText(currentCard.getTvBrandName());
        currentView.tvPrice.setText(currentCard.getTvPrice());
        currentView.tvType.setText(currentCard.getTvType());
    }
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return mainCardList.size();
}

private class MainCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivMainCard;
    TextView tvBrandName;
    TextView tvType;
    TextView tvPrice;

    MainCardViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ivMainCard = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMainCard);
        tvBrandName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBrandName);
        tvType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
        tvPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
    }
}

private class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}
}
```

In your activity :

```
private AdapterRecViewMain adapter;
private RecyclerView rvMain;

@Override protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Logger.logGeneral("onResume()");

    if (adapter == null) {
        setUpRecView();
    }
}

private void setUpRecView() {
    adapter = new AdapterRecViewMain();
    adapter.setData(controller.loadData());
    rvMain = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvMain);
    final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager =
            new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rvMain.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    rvMain.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    rvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rvMain.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set in `RecyclerView` :

```java
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two different XML files and inflate based on position in your Adapter like below.

```
if(position%2==0){
//Inflate Even number layout with 4 images
}else{
//Inflate ODD number layout with 2 images
}
```

Comment: Please explain more. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @mungaihpk, It's quite easy, you just use a different type of view in your adapter based on the type of view you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) in a combination with a [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)?

This combination results in something like this: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYsO_h6I_Hw).

I think, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It is will be much more simpler if you add example

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Staggered-Grid View ,

Extremely simple , easy to use.

Comment: this was in 2015 , life is easier now with Recyclerview and StaggeredGridLayoutManager()

Answer (score -1):

Use Expandable list view and provide different view for each row.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: How would expandable listview help him in this situation?