# Adding Gridview and other list items in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-recyclerview

[image]I need to create a list which contains multiple number of items .
Each item is itself a list of items.
On the top I need to have a gridview of items(2 in each row)  which contains a button to load more gridview items and the list should get expanded on loading more items.
Below the gridview I need to have other items belonging to different types.
I want all of them in a single recycler view.
And yes they contain header text too.

Can somebody please help me in achieving this ?

Comment: draw a picture of what you want first maybe, it's hard to picture what you want just from the brief description. Also, you are supposed to supply code of what you've tried already

Comment: I have added the sample layout.

Comment: question, do you want those two gridview items fixed as header??

Comment: No, The number of gridview items is variable and dynamic. Also the other list items too are dynamic.

Comment: I think this link will help you to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457712/how-to-set-different-columns-for-rows-in-android-gridview