# Multiple number of columns in a single StaggeredGridView?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

Can we have multiple number of columns in a single StaggeredGridView? 
For example 1 column in the first row, 3 columns in second row and 2 columns in 3rd?
Actually, I want to achieve something close to the functionality of Google calendar in which i can freely manage(add, edit, delete) schedules.

Comment: Check out this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457712/how-to-set-different-columns-for-rows-in-android-gridview

Answer (score 1):

Please Try to Check It out the Following link that might be helpful to you in your requirement.
https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Please Let me know If have Any doubt.

Comment: @Arsalan Shah Thanks for Quick Response. Now may be you resolved your Issue.

Comment: This might work fine for me but i see a constraint in this library. It can only allow a maximum column and row span of equal to 2.