# An Android view implementation like Google image search

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Google images search results are display vertical scroll with different images width. Columns count are depend on browser's size.

How to implement a view like Google image search results in Android?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457712/how-to-set-different-columns-for-rows-in-android-gridview

Answer (score 0):

Use staggered gridview in this https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib
library