# Android Listview with different child views

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview, childviews

In my application i need to show a list of objects. In the first row of listview contains single object, but the second row should contain two objects from list. A sample image for my requirement is attached here please go through this. if any idea please share here. Thanks .

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You can use a RecyclerView with GridLayout manager. [Grid Layout Manager Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457712/how-to-set-different-columns-for-rows-in-android-gridview)

Answer (score 1):

In your BaseAdapter do this.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if(position%2 != 0) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_1, null, true);

        // Do action for view 1

    }
    else{
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_2, null, true);

        // Do action for view 2

    }


    return view;
}
```