# How to create Dynamic Gird/Listview in android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I am trying to create dynamic view in my app. In my screen there is multiple rows will be generated dynamically. I want to create dynamic layout for that. Here with I attached the screen design. Please refer that.

[image: Sample image]

Here 1st row have one column and 2nd,3rd rows have 2 columns. Then again 4th column will be 1 row.. Like that I want to create dynamic design. Please let me any idea for this.

Comment: you have to implement your own logic in the adapter to achieve this.

Comment: I think answer you are looking for is in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457712/how-to-set-different-columns-for-rows-in-android-gridview). Here in getSpanSize() method you get position of each view in adapter and depending on position of view you can assign column span.

Comment: @patilmandar2007.. Yes.. I think so.. I will try this and let you know soon...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want achieve is `StaggeredGridView`. It supports multiple columns with varying row size which should help you achieve what you need.

Github Library (Deprecated now): https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid.

Fortunately `RecyclerView` comes with new `LayoutManager` called as `StaggeredGridView`.

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html to get started